# Symfony3 doctrine2 ManyToMany no add in DB in the table where there is just 2 PK

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

I've 3 tables in my DB like this : Article : with idArticle.
Fournissor with idFournissor and in the middle of them there is "Got" who is composed with 1 PK(idFournissor, idArticle).

It is a relation Many to Many. Besides, I have 2 forms : ArticleType and FournissorType, in each form when I submit I have the right values in my DB. 
However, for the champ idFournissor in idArticle or idArticle in idFournissor it is doing anything. I explain : for example, the Article form : I have to choose a fournissor for my article so I choose one of them but in fact in DB it isn't saving something.

I would like that when I submit the form there is in "Got" the value of the id of article and fournissor.

Here is my entity Article, if it can help :

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
   * Article
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="Article",indexe{@ORM\Index(name="I_FK_Article_TypeArticle", columns={"idTypeArticle"})})
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
  class Article
  {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idArticle", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idarticle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="string", length=35, nullable=true)
     */
    private $reference;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="designationFR", type="string", length=160, nullable=true)
     */
    private $designationfr;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="designationEN", type="string", length=160, nullable=true)
     */
    private $designationen;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="plan", type="string", length=70, nullable=true)
     */
    private $plan;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datecreation;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idProduit", type="bigint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $idproduit;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idSousEnsemble", type="bigint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $idsousensemble;

    /**
     * @var \gkeepBundle\Entity\Typearticle
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="gkeepBundle\Entity\Typearticle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idTypeArticle", referencedColumnName="idTypeArticle")
     * })
     */
    private $idtypearticle;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="gkeepBundle\Entity\Fournisseur", mappedBy="idarticle")
     */
    private $idfournisseur;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idfournisseur = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Entity Fournisseur :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="gkeepBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="idfournisseur", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="detient",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idFournisseur", referencedColumnName="idFournisseur")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idArticle", referencedColumnName="idArticle")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $idarticle;
```

Article entity :

```
   /**
 * Add idfournisseur
 *
 * @param \gkeepBundle\Entity\Fournisseur $idfournisseur
 *
 * @return Article
 */
public function addIdfournisseur(\gkeepBundle\Entity\Fournisseur $idfournisseur)
{
    $idfournisseur->set($this);
    $this->idfournisseur[] = $idfournisseur;

    return $this;
}
```

Fournisseur entity :

```
 /**
 * Add idarticle
 *
 * @param \gkeepBundle\Entity\Article $idarticle
 *
 * @return Fournisseur
 */
public function addIdarticle(\gkeepBundle\Entity\Article $idarticle)
{
    $this->idarticle[] = $idarticle;

    return $this;
}
```

Hope that I've been clear, tell me if u don't understand. thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

I think 'cascade persist' was missed. Here is an expample:

Agency User can has many services as well as service can has many users.

```
 // It's Agency Entity
 /**
 * @var Service[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="agencyUsers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="agency_user_services",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $services;

 /**
 * Add services
 *
 * @param ServiceInterface $services
 * @return AgencyAdmin
 */
public function addService(ServiceInterface $services)
{
    $this->services[] = $services;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove services
 *
 * @param ServiceInterface $services
 */
public function removeService(ServiceInterface $services)
{
    $this->services->removeElement($services);
}


//It's Service Entity
/**
 * @var AgencyAdmin[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AgencyAdmin", mappedBy="services")
 */
protected $agencyUsers;

/**
 * Add agencyUsers
 *
 * @param AgencyAdmin $agencyUsers
 * @return Service
 */
public function addAgencyUser(AgencyAdmin $agencyUsers)
{
    $this->agencyUsers[] = $agencyUsers;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove agencyUsers
 *
 * @param AgencyAdmin $agencyUsers
 */
public function removeAgencyUser(AgencyAdmin $agencyUsers)
{
    $this->agencyUsers->removeElement($agencyUsers);
}
```

Comment: Hello @LeshaZ, thanks for your answer, I've now edited my post and I added the other Entity with the 'cascade persist'. However I tried to add a new Article to see if doctrine will add in the table "detient" the value of the two id but it did nothing. Maybe after write `cascade={"persist"}` I have to save the modification by doing another command in my cmd or something like that to register the changement, no ?

Comment: Check please fields name in your DB idFournisseur, idArticle. I suppose it 's id_fournisseur and id_article or idfournisseur and idarticle. E.g @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idFournisseur", referencedColumnName="idFournisseur") shuold has name the same as in DB.

Comment: Re, just checked. Every fields name are correct in doctrine2. I mean the JoinColumn(name="idFournisseur") because in my DB  the PK of Fournisseur is idFournisseur. I checked for all fields and the problem isn't here :(, maybe I should change my setter and getter of Article and Fournisseur, no ?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Check add/remove methods in your entities. Also check  $this->yourField = new ArrayCollection() in both entities constructor.

Comment: I've just checked the constructor, they are good. However, I dont have the same add methods in my entities. For your example, mine isn't "addService" but "addidService". Maybe the problem come from here. I just updated my question to let you see how are made my add methods.